# how to delete or clear printed text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm learning python in Jupyterlab. Currently, I tried to find a way to clear the printed text in Jupyterlab but I haven't gotten any luck.

I searched online to find a few solutions. However, they won't clear the printed text in my console even though others have reported position results.

I tried the 
(1). '\b' character
(2)os.system('cls')
(3)sys.stdout.write

all of them failed to clear the printed text.

```
print('Hello',end='')
print(5*'\b')
print('how are you?',end='')
```

output:
Hell
how are you?

```py
print('Hello',end='')
for i in range(len('Hello')):
    print('\b',end='')

print('how are you?',end='')
```

output:
Hellhow are you?

```py
print('Hey')
import os
if os.name=='nt':
    os.system('cls')
else:
    os.system('clear')
print('how are you?')
```

output:
Hey
how are you?

```py
import sys, time

def delete_last_line():
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[1A')
    sys.stdout.write('\x1b[2K')

print("hello")
time.sleep(2)
delete_last_line()
print("how are you")
```

output:
hello
how are you

I wonder if it's because the system or modules have updated so that the methods no longer work the same way or my computer or Jupyterlab has bugs causing the failure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Be careful of the length, `\r` the cursor returns to the beginning of the line, but it is not overwritten, it is overwritten only from the beginning with the entered text.

```py
print('Hello', end='\r')
# >>> Hello
print('How are you?', end='\r')
# >>> How are you?
print('TEST', end='\r')
# >>> TESTare you?
```

Maybe I would suggest an auxiliary function:

```py
def echo(string, padding=80):
    padding = " " * (padding - len(string)) if padding else ""
    print(string + padding, end='\r')

echo("Hello")
# >>> Hello
echo("How are you?")
# >>> How are you?
echo("TEST")
# >>> TEST
```

Comment: The function is rather ingenious. It solves my problem perfectly. I'm quite shocked, though, that there are no built-in functions or modules (at least I couldn't find them) to address this issue. Clearing the output on the screen and generate new ones seems to be a fundamental ability in most applications.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way and succeed：

```py
import sys

sys.stdout.write('hello\r')
sys.stdout.flush()
sys.stdout.write('how are you\r')

>>>how are you
```

you need to use the sys.stdout.write(info + '\r') to output the information. '\r' means back to the begin of the line without changing lines.

Comment: It worked nicely. Thanks. I wonder if there is a general method that works with print() function though. since print() is what most people call to print text onto the screen.

Comment: This is way more complex than using print() with \r.